# Complex analysis Bruce P. Palka- Ex 5.35

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-continuity

In complex analysis: Let $S = \{ z : z = 0 \text{ or } |\text{Arg } z| \leq \alpha \}$, where $0 < \alpha < \pi$. Verify that the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ is uniformly continuous on $S$, starting by showing that $|f(z) - f(w)| \leq c|z - w|$ for $z$ and $w$ in $S$ satisfying $|z| \geq 1$ and $|w| \geq 1$, where $c = 2^{-1}\sec(\alpha/2)$. Then, focus on the compact set $S \cap \overline{B}(0, 2)$.\

I have tried to solve it in several ways but it is quite complicated or I can't find how to get to the constant c.

Comment: Edit your post to show the  details of what you've tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{w} = \frac{z-w}{\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{w}}.$$

Suppose $z = r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$ and $w=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$. [$\theta_1=Arg(z)$ and $\theta_2 =Arg(w)$.] Notice that $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{w}$ lie either in first or fourth quadrants and hence their real parts are positive. Thus
$$|\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{w}| \geq \Re(\sqrt{z}) + \Re(\sqrt{w}).$$
That is

$$|\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{w}| \geq r_1^{1/2}\cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)+r_2^{1/2}\cos\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right).$$

As both $r_1$ and $r_2$ are greater than or equal to $1$ and as both $\cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)$ are positive, we must have

$$|\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{w}| \geq \cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right)$$

But

$\Big|\frac{\theta_1}{2}\Big| \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ & $\Big| \frac{\theta_2}{2}\Big| \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ and also $0 <\frac{\alpha}{2}< \frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus we must have
$$\cos\left(\frac{\theta_1}{2}\right) \geq \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)$$
and
$$\cos\left(\frac{\theta_2}{2}\right) \geq \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right).$$
Thus
$$|\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{w}| \geq 2 \cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right).$$

This shows that

$$|\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{w}| \leq \frac{|z-w|}{2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)} = 2^{-1}\sec\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)|z-w|.$$

Hope, you can continue with this.

Comment: I think I can continue from here, thank you